# Why is this error occuring in a gradle version, but not a maven one?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, smack

When running an android project using Smack v4.4.6, attempting to access a server via Smack crashes the app and give the following error: `java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.jivesoftware.smack.xml.XmlPullParserFactory: Provider org.jivesoftware.smack.xml.stax.StaxXmlPullParserFactory could not be instantiated`.  The main smack dependencies for this project are

- smack-tcp:4.4.6
- smack-im:4.4.6
- smack-extensions:4.4.6
- smack-java8:4.4.6

However, when the same code was copied to a test project built with maven, and with the same dependencies, the code compiles and runs without error.  Why is this and how can I fix the gradle-built version?

Comment: I suspect you used the wrong dependency kind (api, implementation, ...) when declaring the dependency in graldle. But it's hard to tell without more information (or the a minimal example).

Comment: all gradle dependencies were declared as implementations.  I have double checked this with mvncentral, as this is where i found most of these.